# Get averages from neo4j union result

Tags: neo4j, subquery, cypher, union

I have the following query in neo4j which uses a `UNION`

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'1'})-[dw:DIRECTOR_WEIGHT]->(d:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
WITH m, avg(dw.weight) AS mean_dw, 0 AS mean_aw, 0 AS mean_gw
WHERE m.title = 'Bambi'
RETURN m.title, mean_dw, mean_aw, mean_gw, mean_dw + mean_aw + mean_gw AS total

UNION
MATCH (u:User {userId:'1'})-[aw:ACTOR_WEIGHT]->(a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH m, 0 AS mean_dw, avg(aw.weight) AS mean_aw, 0 AS mean_gw 
WHERE m.title = 'Bambi'
RETURN m.title, mean_dw, mean_aw, mean_gw, mean_dw + mean_aw + mean_gw AS total

UNION
MATCH (u:User {userId:'1'})-[gw:GENRE_WEIGHT]->(g:Genre)<-[:GENRE]-(m:Movie)
WITH m, 0 AS mean_dw, 0 AS mean_aw, avg(gw.weight) AS mean_gw
WHERE m.title = 'Bambi'
RETURN m.title, mean_dw, mean_aw, mean_gw, mean_dw + mean_aw + mean_gw AS total
```

yielding the following result:

```
╒═════════╤═══════════════╤════════════════╤═════════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"m.title"│"mean_dw"      │"mean_aw"       │"mean_gw"        │"total"          │
╞═════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│"Bambi"  │7.2916666666667│"0"             │"0"              │7.2916666666667  │
├─────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│"Bambi"  │"0"            │0.45322110715442│"0"              │0.45322110715442 │
├─────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│"Bambi"  │"0"            │"0"             │9.289617486338933│9.289617486338933│
└─────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

My problem is the "total" doesn't do what I intend it to do, since I only want a single total per movie (i.e. the sum of the three non-zero weights: 7.29 + 0.45 + 9.28),
but I cannot find a way to use this returned result further. I.e., I would like to be able to say say something like

```
RETURN m.title, sum(total)
```

or

```
RETURN m.title, mean_dw + mean_aw + mean_gw
```

*after* getting the union of `mean_dw`, `mean_aw`, and `mean_gw` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While post-union processing isn't currently supported by Cypher, you can get around this with [apoc.cypher.run()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_operations) in APOC procedures. This will let you perform a union within the run and yield the unioned result, allowing you to finish up whatever remaining processing you want.

Though looking at your queries, you're performing identical operations in each one, the only difference is the relationships followed in the matches. There's also some unnecessary work being done for three separate mean columns, as the only thing you're interested in is getting the average of each specific relationship's weight as the mean, and then summing all the means.

That should allow us to cut out some redundant operations and work with a narrower set of variables.

Something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'1'}), (m:Movie{title:'Bambi'})
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
MATCH (u)-[dw:DIRECTOR_WEIGHT]->()-[:DIRECTED]->(m)
RETURN avg(dw.weight) as mean
UNION ALL
MATCH (u)-[aw:ACTOR_WEIGHT]->()-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN avg(aw.weight) AS mean
UNION ALL
MATCH (u)-[gw:GENRE_WEIGHT]->()<-[:GENRE]-(m)
RETURN avg(gw.weight) AS mean
", {u:u, m:m}) YIELD value
RETURN m.title, SUM(value.mean) as total
```

Now, all that said, you don't necessarily need to use unions at all. You can just use subqueries connected with WITH.

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'1'}), (m:Movie{title:'Bambi'})
MATCH (u)-[dw:DIRECTOR_WEIGHT]->()-[:DIRECTED]->(m)
WITH u, m, avg(dw.weight) as total
MATCH (u)-[aw:ACTOR_WEIGHT]->()-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WITH u, m, total + avg(aw.weight) AS total
MATCH (u)-[gw:GENRE_WEIGHT]->()<-[:GENRE]-(m)
WITH u, m, total + avg(gw.weight) AS total
RETURN m.title, total
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second version works; the first version gives a different (and wrong) result, though I can't figure out why from the code. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas, on sample data both queries are returning identical results for me. For the first query, you may want to `RETURN value` to see each of the means before they are summed together, and see if that matches what you expect.